# SQLite Updating

Tags: android, sqlite

I read many many doc and I don't know why my code isn't working.
I want to update my table and this is my code:

```
public boolean updateSetting(int id, String cordinates, String ip, String port, String message, String sendTime) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    try {
        //contentValues.put(clmKeyId,0);
        if (cordinates!=null) {
            contentValues.put(clmCordinates, cordinates);
        }
        contentValues.put(clmIp, ip);
        contentValues.put(clmPort, port);
        contentValues.put(clmDeviceMessage, message);
        contentValues.put(clmSendTime, sendTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int checkUpdate = db.update(tblSetting, contentValues,clmSettingKeyId + " = "+ id,null);

    db.close();
        return checkUpdate>0;
    }
```

and this is my calling method:

```
    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        boolean value = dataBaseHelper.updateSetting(0, cordinates, edtIdp.getText().toString().trim(), edtport.getText().toString().trim(), edtMessage.getText().toString().trim(), edtSendTime.getText().toString().trim());
        if (value)
            //doSomthing
}
```

but my  `update Setting`method always return 0.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are passing **0** as the **id** used to identify the row to be updated. Assuming that you are using the typical use of a column named **id** (i.e. it's an alias of the rowid column and defined as `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with or without the AUTOINCREMENT keyword)) then **id** will not be **0**. The first **id** assigned will be **1**, then likely **2** and then likely **3** as new rows are inserted.....

As such you will get 0 returned because there are no rows to update due to the WHERE clause of the UPDATE.

If you changed the **0** to **1** then it is likely that the update would work (again assuming typical use of an id column and that no rows have been deleted) so, perhaps try :-

```
dataBaseHelper.updateSetting(1, cordinates, edtIdp.getText().toString().trim(), edtport.getText().toString().trim(), edtMessage.getText().toString().trim(), edtSendTime.getText().toString().trim());
```

Ideally though, you need to identify exactly what row needs to be updated (i.e. get a valid **id**, perhaps via a list presented to a user).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you got every time 0 because of below line:-

```
dataBaseHelper.updateSetting(0, cordinates, edtIdp.getText().toString().trim(), edtport.getText().toString().trim(), edtMessage.getText().toString().trim(), edtSendTime.getText().toString().trim());
```

Please make your **id is Autoincrement in tblSetting**. and then replace your above line to below:-

```
dataBaseHelper.updateSetting(cordinates, edtIdp.getText().toString().trim(), edtport.getText().toString().trim(), edtMessage.getText().toString().trim(), edtSendTime.getText().toString().trim());
```

**Your id will be automatically take and you no need to give it manually.**

Please try it may be helps you.